# Python request login on tplinkcloud

Tags: python, authentication, request

I'm trying to login to my TPLINKCLOUD account through Python..
With Tamper, I can see that the request is on https://www.tplinkcloud.com/init3.php

So I've tried with this one:

> import requests
>
> payload = {
>       'account': 'mail@mail.com',
>       'password': 'password' }
>
> with requests.Session() as s:
>
> ```
>   p = s.post('https://www.tplinkcloud.com/init3.php', data=payload)
> ```
>
> print p.text

But I've a blank response.. I also tried with https://www.tplinkcloud.com/ without /init3.php and the response is the main page without login done.

How can I resolve ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `print p.status_code`, you will see `403`, that means you will be forbidden by this site until you have post right username and password!

Comment: I've tried with p.status_code and yes, the result is 403. But the value (username, password) is correct.. Is there other way to understand the problem?

Comment: This is the POST request in TAMPER:

DATA%5Baccount%5D=email@email.it&DATA%5Bpassword%5D=0BsiuFPGCis/bRqDrwU16SMyUQqR+ZUFTkFim6nW4tiKQfnHXN8GYD7Kr1aRa8Olb28yaEyjrHsQMnFFSJPAJb/l38EK4VM+mcH3QwLX8Wmx3Qxg5GMO2QXJ6NdctkV8t1IcrHOPdpESzf2kjHDD5lZV7SZfaviCl7fwnqhGA2Q=&REQUEST=LOGIN

Comment: `payload = { 'DATA[account]': 'mail@mail.com', 'DATA[password]': 'password','REQUEST':'LOGIN' }` may work!

Comment: You should encrypt your password before posting to the website, but I don't know the rule, check the rule and encrypt your password first!

Comment: Thank you Nick.. Now, i've "200" message code with the following: {"errorCode":1023,"msg":"Decrypt password failed"}
Yes.. I've to understand how to encrypt password!! 
I'm trying to search on the net.. thank you so much

Comment: That's because you haven't encrypted your password!

Comment: Is there a way to know what encryption is ?

Comment: Yes, encryption rule can be found by reading javascript files of `https://www.tplinkcloud.com/ `.

Comment: I have found the encryption rule, it is just in a javascript file which can be read or downloaded through `https://d2baw28zdve8g3.cloudfront.net/ssl/common/lib/rsapublic.js?v=1490941812`, called  `rsa_encrypt` function, which begin from line 190.

Comment: Maybe my English is not good enough yet, hope you can understand my meaning!

Comment: If you want to get your encrypted password, the simplest way is: in Chrome, open `https://www.tplinkcloud.com/`, type `ctrl+shift+I(win/Linux)` to open the console, then type `rsa_encrypt('your password')` to get your encrypted password!

Comment: Don't worry for your english. I don't speak english well too... :-) Thank you for reply. Can I encrypt my password in python script ?

Comment: Of course, you can, the prerequisite is you grasp javascript.

Comment: So good.. I've found rsapublic.js and function.. I've discovered a new thing.. thanks

Comment: Good job，have fun!